# how can i recover the error(Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Work Station\Works\NewThrissurDiary\images\'.) that i got in my update query?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I want to update the files which I uploaded to database

This is my query.. please help...

```
   if (FileUpload1.HasFile || FileUpload2.HasFile || FileUpload3.HasFile || FileUpload4.HasFile || FileUpload5.HasFile)
   {
            string filename1 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename1));

            string filename2 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename2));

            string filename3 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload3.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename3));

            //string filename4 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload4.PostedFile.FileName);
            //FileUpload4.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename4));

            string filename5 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload5.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload5.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename5));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

even It is an old Topic....
But I have recently gotten same Error... The Error Try to access the pathe which is not available. Let me say as my example :
I Have a folder (Fa) which belongs to My Experts and The main Path where records upload files are In another folder (Fb)...
At First I wrote this Code  :

```
string strname2;
        strname2 = ("Fa/" + FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("//") + 1));
        LabelFile.Text = strname2;
```

and when I use Following Error I got that deadly Error :

```
     if (strname2 != "Fa/")
            {
                FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strname2));
            }
            else
            {
                LabelFile.Text = "";
            }
```

After some test and try I change both above code to following Codes and Guess what? Everything works like a charm :

## 1:

```
string strname2;
        strname2 = ("../Fb/Fa/" + FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("//") + 1));
        LabelFile.Text = strname2;
```

And then:

## 2:

```
     if (strname2 != "../Fb/Fa/")
            {
                FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strname2));
            }
            else
            {
                LabelFile.Text = "";
            }
```

Now the solution is check your folders and see that folders are available or not.

PS: Search specially for this folder : `NewThrissurDiary`

Hope this Help you